# Chinese inscription teapot

Tags: simplified-characters

I want to find out what these symbols mean so I can find an approximate age. I have no experience with Chinese symbols any help would be really appreciated.  Thank you. [image]

Comment: Can you post a clearer picture? And also can you show what you've tried to figure out the inscription?

Comment: This is Japanese and it says 鐵鑄 (“鉄鋳”).

Comment: cast iron kettle (tetsubin) are, most likely, japanese product. these two characters should be treated as kanji. i would suggest you ask in japanese language stack exchange: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The image is quite blurry but I think it says 铁铸, which are simplified Chinese characters meaning cast iron.

Answer (score 0):

I can only see that they are traditional Chinese characters. the first one is "鉄"， it means "iron", a kind of metal.

Your photo is not clear enough to see, can you post a clearer one?

Comment: 鉄 is not a Traditional Chinese character...

Comment: @droooze Isn't 鉄 listed in the Kangxi dictionary? http://www.kangxizidian.com/kangxi/1300.gif

Comment: @Flux I'm not sure that being listed in the Kangxi dictionary means that something is a Traditional Chinese Character. Simplified Chinese, as a concept, did not exist until the turn of the 19th century; the Kangxi dictionary lists out the difference between Orthodox (正) and Vulgar (俗) forms, and 鉄 is a vulgar form, if you read that picture closely: 《正字通》俗用爲鐡字誤